# Read fails to read all bytes - even though its not EOF? (C)

Tags: c, file, struct

I'm trying to write a struct to a file , write a single char at the end to make the file's size 1M, and then read the struct to another variable. 
The size of the struct is 4424 bytes, however, read returns 2018 - and no matter how many times I run it again, it wont read any bytes afterwards. That doesn't make sense, given I just wrote 4K bytes into it.

Here is the struct:

```
typedef struct alloc_table_record{
char fileName[MAXIMUM_FILE_NUM]; //100
ssize_t fileSize;
mode_t fileProtect;
time_t insertionTime;
ssize_t db1Size;
off_t db1Offset;
ssize_t db2Size;
off_t db2Offset;
ssize_t db3Size;
off_t db3Offset;
bool valid;

}TableRec;

typedef struct catalog_t{
off_t totalSize;
ssize_t overallSize;
time_t creatTime;
time_t modTime;
short fileAmount;
short blocksInUse;
ssize_t lastSpot;
TableRec allocTable[MAXIMUM_FILE_NUM]; //100

}Catalog;
```

The code:

```
Catalog newCat;
newCat.lastSpot = 1024*1024; //some input value
//... initializing field
int fd = open(fileName,O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC,0755);
ssize_t wrote = write(fd, &newCat, sizeof(newCat)); //wrote is 4424
off_t offset = lseek(fd, newCat.lastSpot - 1, SEEK_SET);
wrote = write(fd, "0", 1);
lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
Catalog obj2;    
ssize_t readGood = read(fd, &obj2, sizeof(obj2)); //readGood is 2018
ssize_t readGood2 = read(fd, (char*)(&obj2) + readGood, sizeof(obj2)-readGood); // readGood2 is 0
```

Comment: I can't really tell what's wrong, but there is a slight chance that your runtime refrains from reading from disk into invalid memory locations, and your second read ***is*** reading into an invalid memory location, since `&obj2 + readGood` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: also it would have been nice if you had refrained from throwing red herrings into the question, like that weird business with writing a "0".

Comment: @MikeNakis This is not the case, because even if I drop the' + readGood ', it returns 0 still.

Also, why isn't it like adding +1 to a char* pointer for example, changing the base adress from 0 to 1?

Comment: yes, that's probably not the problem.  You would encounter it later when it would crash and burn if it read anything greater than zero.  That's because `&obj2` is a `Catalog*`, not a `char*`.

Comment: So, how do you know you wrote 4K bytes into it?

Comment: "why isn't it like adding +1 to a char* pointer?" It is: pointer arithmetic adds the *size of the element* (not 1 although in the case of `char*` it is 1 by definition). In the same way that when indexing an array, you do not consider the size of the element.

Comment: @MikeNakis Ah I see, so it actually moves readGood*sizeof(Catalog) , right?

Comment: it moves `readGood*1` when the unit of measurement is `Catalog`.  It moves `readGood*sizeof(Catalog)` if the unit of measurement is bytes.

Comment: @MikeNakis While debugging, wrote is 4424. Worth mentioning that I tried running the code on an Ubuntu VM. Oddly enough, it reads all the bytes there... (Ran on  windows 10 before).

Comment: Have you tried deleting any existing file before running the code?  Have you tried changing the permissions to something more liberal like 0777?

Comment: I haven't, I'll try and report back.

Comment: Hmm.. it still does the same problem. Refusing to read more than 2018 bytes for some reason.

Comment: This is weird.  Try posting an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (after stripping all unnecessary stuff) so that someone with a C/C++ compiler might help you.

Comment: Add `O_BINARY` to `open` flags.

Comment: You need to serialize the record (as `fileName` is a pointer).

Comment: You should have mentioned that the problem was on Windows particularly since you're using POSIX APIs (what toolchain are you using?).  As @user58697 pointed out you need the `O_BINARY` flag set on Windows. It doesn't matter on Unix systems because text mode doesn't do anything special there, but on Windows it'll cause translation of cr/lf sequences to newlines (and vice-versa when writing) *and* treat a `^Z` character in the stream as an indication of EOF.

Comment: `&obj2 + readGood` -> `(char *)&obj2 + readGood`

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks, that was very detailed. I'm using mingw btw.
Also, regarding the text mode in windows - does that mean that if I want to write "crocs" to a file, it will show up like:
"/nocs" (new line then "ocs") 
if its in text mode? Never noticed!

Comment: I believe that the Windows newline translation that occurs in text mode is: when writing, a `'\n'` character is written as `\x0d\x0a` and when reading a sequence of `\x0d\x0a` is presented as `'\n'`.  I'm honestly not sure what happens to a `\x0d` byte that isn't paired with `\x0a` - I think the runtime leaves it alone, but I'd have to experiment.

Comment: The posted code is missing the critical `#include` statements so does not compile!   Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files your actual code uses?

Comment: the posted code does not contain any function definitions, most importantly the `main()` function.  Are you expecting us to rewrite your code so it will compile?

Comment: when calling: `open()`, `write()`, `lseek()`, `read()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the function: `write()` returns a `ssize_t`, not a `size_t`   The code will need the `ssize_t` when checking for any failure of the call to `write()`.   The function: `read()` returns a `ssize_t` not a `size_t`  The code will need the `ssize_t` when checking for any failure of the call to `read()`

Comment: the code should avoid declaring types with names that end in `_t` because, per the standard, such names are 'reserved' for the environment.

Comment: the macro: `MAXIMUM_FILE_NUM` is not defined within the scope of the posted code.

Comment: this file mode value: `0755` is saying the file is executable,  That is not true and should not be used.  Suggest: `0666`  which means anyone can read/write the file.    You also need to note the value of the environment variable `umask` as that has a profound effect on the resulting file permissions (it mostly limits the permissions that the program can apply to the file.

Comment: this line: `wrote = write(fd, "0", 1);` is writing a char with the value 0x30 to the end of the file.  is that what you really want to do?

Comment: in the `struct alloc_table_record`, the field: `char *fileName`  even if set to some address, will mean NOTHING when read in by a program, even the same program.  It really needs to be an array of char, similar to `char fileName[100];`    Which will upset the sizing expected in the code.  Otherwise it is 2 or 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the underlying architecture.

Comment: this line: `size_t readGood2 = read(fd,  (char *)&obj2 + readGood, sizeof(obj2));` would be much better written as: `ssize_t readGood2 = read(fd,  (char*)(&obj2) + readGood, sizeof(obj2)-readGood);`

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for the input, the whole code is above 1k lines and it includes checking the returned values of read/write and all the include commands. I wanted to present a short code representing the problem I ran into, so I avoided adding lines that aren't directly related to the problem.

Comment: part of the requirements for runtime problems are: post code that cleanly compiles, is short, and still exhibits the problem.